# Please fix this shop code. I don't know how I can fix it

Tags: python, class, object

The following is a code for a shop. It has two problems:
1 - The total value when I print out the shop stock is not correct.
2 - In the customer function, the system for selecting items and their quantity isnt working too.

I'm new to python and I am not sure what to do here. I have been stuck for 2 days on this now. Please help me in fixing these two problems

```
#===========================================#SHOP#========================================================#
import random as rd

class shop():
    def __init__(self,name,address):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address

    def stock_input(self):
        self.n = int(input("Enter how many item you would like to input into the stock: "))
        self.item_list = []
        self.item_names = []
        self.item_prices = []
        self.item_quantities = []
        self.tots = []
        for i in range(1,self.n+1):
            print("")
            print("=========================================================================================")
            self.item_name = input("Enter item name: ")
            self.item_price = float(input("Enter item price: "))
            self.item_quantity = int(input("Enter stock of item: "))
            self.tot = self.item_price * self.item_quantity
            self.item = "NAME: ",self.item_name," PRICE: ",self.item_price," STOCK: ",self.item_quantity," TOTAL PRICE: ",self.tot
            self.item_names.append(self.item_name)
            self.item_prices.append(self.item_price)
            self.item_quantities.append(self.item_quantity)
            self.tots.append(self.tot)
            self.item_list.append(self.item_name)
            print("=========================================================================================")
        print("")
    
    def stock_display(self):
        self.j = 1
        self.k = 0
        self.total = 0
        print("")
        print("=========================================================================================")
        print("\t\t\t\t\tSTOCK")
        print("=========================================================================================")
        print("S.no\t\tItem Name\t\tItem Price\tItem Stock\t\tTotal Cost")
        for i in range(1,self.n+1):
            print(self.j,"\t\t",self.item_names[self.k],"\t\t",self.item_prices[self.k],"\t\t",self.item_quantities[self.k],"\t\t\t",self.tots[self.k])
            self.total=self.total+self.item_prices[self.k]
            self.j+=1
            self.k+=1
        
        print("=========================================================================================")
        print("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTOTAL: ",self.total)
        print("=========================================================================================")
    
    def customer(self):
        self.nam = input("Enter customer name: ")
        self.random = "1234567890"
        self.bill_id = ""
        self.cart_names = []
        self.cart_price = []
        self.cart_quantity = []

        for i in range(1,5):
            i = rd.choice(self.random)
            self.bill_id+=i
        
        self.number = int(input("How many items would you like to buy: "))
        print("We have the following items: ", self.item_names)
        self.k = 0
        print("=========================================================================================")

        for i in range(1,self.n+1):
            print("Stock of ",self.item_names[self.k],": ",self.item_quantities[self.k],". PRICE: ",self.item_prices[self.k])
            self.k+=1
        
        print("=========================================================================================")
        self.k = 0
        for i in range(1,self.number):
            self.k = 0
            self.itmname = input("What product would you like to buy: ")
            for j in range(i):
                if self.itmname == self.item_names[self.k]:
                    self.itmquantity = int(input("How much of this item would you like to buy: "))
                    if self.itmquantity > self.item_prices[self.k]:
                        print("This is not possible. We are setting it so that you have all the stock of that item.")
                        self.itmquantity = self.item_prices[self.k]
                        print("Your total is: ", self.tots[self.k])
                        self.k=0
                    else:
                        print("Done.")
                        print("Your total is: ",self.itmquantity*self.item_prices[self.k])
                        self.k = 0
                
                else:
                    self.k +=1
            

object =shop(input("Enter shop name: "),input("Enter shop address: "))
object.stock_input()
object.stock_display()
object.customer()
```

1. Total Value of stock:
   I used a variable self.k in a for loop to display the stock items while simultaneously adding up the values. However, while the items were being displayed properly, the total was not correct:
   Code:

```
self.j = 1
        self.k = 0
        self.total = 0
        print("")
        print("=========================================================================================")
        print("\t\t\t\t\tSTOCK")
        print("=========================================================================================")
        print("S.no\t\tItem Name\t\tItem Price\tItem Stock\t\tTotal Cost")
        for i in range(1,self.n+1):
            print(self.j,"\t\t",self.item_names[self.k],"\t\t",self.item_prices[self.k],"\t\t",self.item_quantities[self.k],"\t\t\t",self.tots[self.k])
            self.total=self.total+self.item_prices[self.k]
            self.j+=1
            self.k+=1
        
        print("=========================================================================================")
        print("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTOTAL: ",self.total)
        print("=========================================================================================")
```

2. Customer item selection system:
   This too isnt working and I am not sure why. I have tried using nested for loops to go through the items list and find the one that matches the user's choice. Also, even when it selects the item, it shows an error right after when it tries to show how much the user wants to buy. Here is the code:
   Code:

```
for i in range(1,self.number):
            self.k = 0
            self.itmname = input("What product would you like to buy: ")
            for j in range(i):
                if self.itmname == self.item_names[self.k]:
                    self.itmquantity = int(input("How much of this item would you like to buy: "))
                    if self.itmquantity > self.item_prices[self.k]:
                        print("This is not possible. We are setting it so that you have all the stock of that item.")
                        self.itmquantity = self.item_prices[self.k]
                        print("Your total is: ", self.tots[self.k])
                        self.k=0
                    else:
                        print("Done.")
                        print("Your total is: ",self.itmquantity*self.item_prices[self.k])
                        self.k = 0
                
                else:
                    self.k +=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must multiply the price of each product with its quantity in order to have the correct cost:

```py
self.total = self.total + self.item_prices[self.k] * self.item_quantities[self.k]
```

2. Below the changed code of *Customer item selection system*. Explanation in the comments.

```py
self.number = int(input("How many items would you like to buy: "))

self.show_products()

self.k = 0

for i in range(0, self.number):
    self.k = 0
    self.itmname = input("What product would you like to buy: ")

    # we loop over item_list so as to check if itmname corresponds to a product
    for j in range(len(self.item_list)):
        if self.itmname == self.item_names[self.k]:
            self.itmquantity = int(input("How much of this item would you like to buy: "))

            # we check if the wanted itmquantity is more than quantity of the product AND NOT its price as you previously did
            if self.itmquantity > self.item_quantities[self.k]:
                print("This is not possible. We are setting it so that you have all the stock of that item.")

                # we set itmquantity as the one in the stock (NOT as the price you had)
                self.itmquantity = self.item_quantities[self.k]
                # set quantity of item as 0
                self.item_quantities[self.k] = 0
                print("Your total is: ", self.itmquantity * self.item_prices[self.k])

                self.k = 0
            else:
                # Subtract the quantity sold
                self.item_quantities[self.k] -= self.itmquantity
                print("Done.")
                print("Your total is: ", self.itmquantity * self.item_prices[self.k])
                self.k = 0

            # Show up the products with the updated quantities
            self.show_products()

            break # continue in the next product when we are done with this
        else:
            self.k += 1


# Create a function so as to improve read-ability
def show_products(self):
    print("We have the following items: ", self.item_names)
    self.k = 0
    print("=========================================================================================")

    for i in range(1, self.n + 1):
        print("Stock of ", self.item_names[self.k], ": ", self.item_quantities[self.k], ". PRICE: ",
              self.item_prices[self.k])
        self.k += 1

    print("=========================================================================================")
```